# Get class name of top child

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working in objective c/cocos2d. I have a scene named `AllLevelAndModes` which I add a CCScrollView named `levelScroll` of type class `EasyLevelSelectScene`. On this level scroller, I have a bunch of buttons for my game level. When someone touches one of the buttons, a popup comes up displaying some stats about the level. I add this popup by add childing it to `EasyLevelSelectScene` when a button is tapped. This child is of kind of class `LevelSelectDropdown`. I want to make a functionality such that if a user taps outside the popup (which is smaller than the whole screen), that the popup disappears.

Now I suppose I could get the size of the popup and the screen and if a user taps outside of some range of x and y, the popup disappears. But that is a little cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this? I was trying to basically get the name of the class that is tapped by running the following code once the popup comes.

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchLocationTemp = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: [touch locationInView:touch.view]];
    CCResponderManager *responder = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] responderManager];
    CCNode *node = [responder nodeAtPoint:touchLocationTemp];
    CCLOG(@"class type %@", node); //Always reads 'EasyLevelSelectScene' no matter where I tap

    if([node isKindOfClass:[EasyLevelSelectScene class]]) {
        //go back to level select screen
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work though, since wherever I tap it logs `EasyLevelSelectScene`, even when I tap right on top of my popup! Why is it doing this, and is there a way to get the class name of the top-most child? Thanks for the help!

Comment: you may use the popup library readily available in [GitHub](https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController).

Comment: I don't think this supports CCNodes...only UIViewControllers